# Removing commas and empty tags from a string using regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am trying to filter out spam before being posted using a few routines and external services (akismet) but they all seem to fail when pushing in a comma delimited word or a word formed with empty tags. Eg

b[u][/u]u[u][/u]y[i][/i]m[b][/b] e <-> buyme

b,u,y,m,e <-> buyme

Does anyone know of a good ColdFusion regex to strip out this sort of behavior before I can post it to aksimet for processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly: **Have you checked whether is Akismet not already doing this?**

I would very much suspect it already does all this processing (and more), so you don't actually need to.

---

Anyway, assuming this is bbcode, and thus the relevant tags will be for bold/italic/underline, you can replace them with:

```
TextForAkismet = rereplace( TextForAkismet , '\[([biu])\]\[/\1\]' , '' , 'all' )
```

If there are other empty tags you want to remove, simply update the captured group (the bit in parentheses) as appropriate. To also cater for potentially attributes (but still an empty tag), a quick and dirty way is to use `[^\]]*` after the tag name (outside the captured group).

```
'\[([biu]|img|url)[^\]]*\]\[/\1\]'
```

Depending on the dialect of bbcode you're working with, you may need to handle quoted brackets which would need a more complex expression.

To remove commas that appear between letters, use:

```
TextForAkismet = rereplace( TextForAkismet , '\b,\b' , '' , 'all' )
```

(Where `\b` matches any position between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric.)